# Matching only some words in a Postgres full text search

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, postgresql-9.1

I'm interested in using postgres as the search engine for a website I'm developing, but it seems that postgres is very strict when matching ts_query and ts_vector types. If a ts_vector doesn't contain all items in the query, the match is rejected.

For example I would expect the query 'Stack Overflow code' to match the Stack Overflow site summary, but it doesn't because the word 'code' isn't present, even though 'Stack' and 'Overflow' are.

```
SELECT 
to_tsvector('Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. It''s built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we''re working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming.')
@@ 
plainto_tsquery('english', 'Stack Overflow code')
```

Returns:

```
false
```

In my use case, I'm not interested in exact matches because this is going to be used by users to search the website.

**Is there a way to count something as a match when only part of the query is in the document?**

Comment: see also the smlar extension, written by the same authors as text search

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because `plainto_tsquery` chops the string into separate lexemes and puts the & (AND) operator between them. That means it matches ALL words.

If you want the | (OR) operator, you need to write your own "parser". For example, you could replace all occurrences of `' '` with `'|'`

```
SELECT 
to_tsvector('Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. It''s built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we''re working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming.')
@@ 
to_tsquery('english', replace('Stack Overflow Code', ' ' , '|'));
```